# RTSP with iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, video-streaming, rtsp

My partner and I are developing an app for a client where they have a camera that connects to the app. Currently it is running in http but we want to use RTSP. We scraped the internet today to look for possible ideas, but they all seem outdated.

We tried incorporating [DFURTSPPlayer](https://github.com/durfu/DFURTSPPlayer) but kept getting compile errors that were related to the actual SDK.

We want to use something like [VideoStreamSDK](http://www.videostreamsdk.com/).

Does anyone have any ways they can point us towards?

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone tried gstreamer that has build for iOS and HW decoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

We found a [RTSP player](https://github.com/iMoreApps/ffmpeg-avplayer-for-ios) essentially that we were able to just incorporate it easily into our project.

[edit:
This requires to purchase their license :( , currently it is not working and throws error:  Error Domain=com.imoreapps.avplayer.errordomain Code=-149]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with `MobileVLCKit`? it's really easy and work well!
I wrote a small example here: https://github.com/rvi/ONVIFCamera

If you want to try it, just type `pod try ONVIFCamera` in your terminal.

Here is how to do it:

```
var mediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()

// Associate the movieView to the VLC media player
mediaPlayer.drawable = self.movieView

let url = URL(string: "rtsp://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/params")
let media = VLCMedia(url: url)
mediaPlayer.media = media

mediaPlayer.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

I successfully compiled and used DFURTSPPlayer but it crashed on some iOS devices.

Some days ago I have integrated this solution for playing rtsp video stream from IP-cameras: https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer

The only issue I have is not stable connection. Player established connection only after few attempts.

Comment: No. This issues is rare and does not affect the quality of work))